# Spring OAuth2.0: Getting User Roles based on Client Id

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have multiple clients registered for my oauth2 auth server. lets say **user1** have roles such as `ROLE_A`, `ROLE_B` for **client1**, same user has roes such as `ROLE_C`, `ROLE_D` for **client2**. now when the user logins either using **client1** or **client2** he is able to see all the four roles ie. `ROLE_A`, `ROLE_B`, `ROLE_C` and `ROLE_D`.

My requirement was when the **user1** logins to **client1** it should return only the roles `ROLE_A` and `ROLE_B`. when he logins using **client2** it should return only `ROLE_C` and `ROLE_D`

For achieving this, what I planned is within the authenticate function, I need to get the clientId. so using the clientId and the username I can find the corresponding roles allocated to the user from the db (client-user-roles-mapping table). .But the issue is I don't know how to get the **clientId** within the authenticate function

```
 @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userName = ((String) authentication.getPrincipal()).toLowerCase();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        if (userName != null && authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
                String clientId = // HERE HOW TO GET THE CLIENT ID 
                Set<String> userRoles = authRepository.getUserRoleDetails(userName.toLowerCase(), clientId);
                Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = fillUserAuthorities(userRoles);
                Authentication token =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, StringUtils.EMPTY, authorities);
                return token;
            } else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Failed!!!");
            }
         } else {
             throw new BadCredentialsException("Username or Password cannot be empty!!!");
         }         
    }
```

Can anyone please help me on this

**UPDATE 1**

**CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private LDAPAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthentication;

    @Autowired
    private AuthRepository authRepository;

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            String userName = ((String) authentication.getPrincipal()).toLowerCase();
            String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
            if (userName != null && authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
                    String clientId = // HERE HOW TO GET THE CLIENT ID 
                    Set<String> userRoles = authRepository.getUserRoleDetails(userName.toLowerCase(), clientId);
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = fillUserAuthorities(userRoles);
                    Authentication token =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, StringUtils.EMPTY, authorities);
                    return token;
                } else {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Failed!!!");
                }
             } else {
                 throw new BadCredentialsException("Username or Password cannot be empty!!!");
             }         
    }


    public boolean invokeAuthentication(String username, String password, Boolean isClientValidation) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> userDetails = ldapAuthentication.authenticateUser(username, password);
            if(Boolean.parseBoolean(userDetails.get("success").toString())) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Exception in invokeAuthentication::: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

    private Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> fillUserAuthorities(Set<String> roles) {
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorties = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        for(String role : roles) {
            authorties.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorties;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can access the request in spring using HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest(); in any part of your code and then get the Authorization header and decode it and then you will have the clientId

Comment: @Shadi hey this is pretty cool.....works fine....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is you code after modification

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String userName = ((String) authentication.getPrincipal()).toLowerCase();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    if (userName != null && authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            String clientId = getClientId();
            // validate client ID before use
            Set<String> userRoles = authRepository.getUserRoleDetails(userName.toLowerCase(), clientId);
            Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = fillUserAuthorities(userRoles);
            Authentication token =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, StringUtils.EMPTY, authorities);
            return token;
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Failed!!!");
        }
     } else {
         throw new BadCredentialsException("Username or Password cannot be empty!!!");
     }         


private  String getClientId(){
    final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    final String authorizationHeaderValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String base64AuthorizationHeader = Optional.ofNullable(authorizationHeaderValue)
            .map(headerValue->headerValue.substring("Basic ".length())).orElse("");

    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(base64AuthorizationHeader)){
        String decodedAuthorizationHeader = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64AuthorizationHeader), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        return decodedAuthorizationHeader.split(":")[0];
    }

    return "";
}
```

more info about  [RequestContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html)

Answer (score 2):

## Extend `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

---

A POJO is required to hold not just the username and the password but also the client identifier.

```
public ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
  private final String clientId;

  public ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal
                                                    , Object credentials
                                                    , String clientId) {
    super(principal, credentials);

    this.clientId = clientId;
  }

  public String getClientId() { return clientId; }
}
```

## Extend `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

---

The authentication process needs to be tweaked so that the client identifier is passed to the authentication code in addition to the username and password.

```
public class ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
  public ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter () { super(); }

  @Override
  public public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request
                                                    , HttpServletResponse response)
                                                    throws AuthenticationException {
    // See the source code of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
    // to implement this. Instead of creating an instance of
    // UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, create an instance of
    // ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, something along
    // the lines of:

    final String username = obtainUsername(request);
    final String password = obtainPassword(request);
    final String clientId = obtainClientId(request);

    ...

    final Authentication authentication = new ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, clientId);

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication);
  }
}
```

## Use the extra information available for logging in

---

```
public CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
  ...

  @Override
  public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.isAssignableFrom(ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }


  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication)
                                     throws AuthenticationException {
  }
}
```

## Force Spring Security to use the custom filter

---

```
<bean class="com.path.to.filter.ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" id="formAuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<http ... >
  <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="formAuthenticationFilter"/>

  ...
</http>
```

or, if using Java configuration:

```
@Bean
public ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
  final ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();

  filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

  return filter;
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.addFilterAt(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish for the reply, can you give me a little bit info based on the where to extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and relevant java config for `Force Spring Security to use the custom filter`

Comment: no parameter for `usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` function.   `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.addFilterAt(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
      ...
}`

Comment: @AlexMan, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has an `authenticationManager` method that returns the current `AuthenticationManager` in use. The general outline of the solution has been provided in the answer. You must put the rest of the pieces together through your own effort instead of expecting users to write the entire code for you to avoid [help vampire tendencies](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, since you want to just access additional parameters from the request, you could try out the following in your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` class

```
@Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Add the following logic to read the httpRequest parameters and add your logic to access the authorization key

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Header Name - " + headerName + ", Value - " + request.getHeader(headerName));
   }
}
```

Now, you will have the encode Basic Authentication field which you can decode like the one below

```
if (authorization != null && authorization.startsWith("Basic")) {
        // Authorization: Basic base64credentials
        String base64Credentials = authorization.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        String credentials = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Credentials),
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        // client/secret = clientId:secret
        final String[] values = credentials.split(":",2);
```